# conversion of decimal to hexadecimal in Embedded C

Tags: microcontroller

I want to convert decimal number to hexadecimal in Embedded C.

Actually in my project input to controller is decimal which will be subtracted from hexadecimal value, so I need a conversion.

I tried to write it but after converting a number (`75` for example) to its hexadecimal equivalent it will be (`411`). The trouble is that I did not know how to convert a number like `11` to `b` in hexadecimal as you know that there is no `11` in hexadecimal, it is `b`; so please help.

I want to save the converted value in a flag (for subtracting), not for printing. I can print a hex value by simple put a condition like:

```
(if (a > 10) printf("b"))
```

but this is not a solution for Embedded.

So please give me a complete solution.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "which will be subtracted from hexadecimal value"? Hexadecimal is just a representation of the number. It's not a different value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but your integer is just the "type of interpretation". In your memory it's just a bunch of 0 and 1, and therefore you can also presentate that "data" in an decimal, hexadecimal way.

If you need it as input for a register, you can just pass it into it. 
Or do I missunderstand your problem?